# R Programming: Append data in a dataframe within running nested loops

Tags: r, append, nested-loops

I have following code.

```
    for(i in seq(from=1, to=8, by=1)) #i is number of stocks from a list
    {
        for(j in seq(from=1, to=8, by=1)) #j is number of trading days from another list
        {
            ## Matching bid and ask prices of each stock for each date and update temp_table
            select_output <- sqldf("select * from temp_table where FLAG == 'new' ")
        }
    }
```

In current scenario only the last iteration data is staying in `select_output` which is expected. I want to keep the file open to populate it with data from all the iterations. I don't want to use another loop for inserting data into `select_output`. Is there any other way possible in R? Please suggest if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

one option is to combine expand.grid, apply and do.call

```
index <- expand.grid(
  i = 1:8,
  j = 1:8
)
results <- apply(index, 1, function(x){
   x["i"] # holds i
   x["j"] # holds j
   sqldf("select * from temp_table where FLAG == 'new' ")
})
do.call(rbind, results)
```

Comment: no I have more operations inside nested loops. So this way it will be not possible. I am taking data from other dataframes based on i and j positions. I am hoping - if keeping my nested loop intact, you can suggest something on appending data in `select_output`.

Comment: Why can't you do those other operations inside the function within `apply`, using `x["i"]` and `x["j']`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually an R weak point. The best thing to do is probably:

```
results <- data.frame(a=numeric(0), b=character(0), ...) # whatever columns you expect
for(i in 1:8) for(j in s1:7) {
        ## Your code...
        select_output <- sqldf("select * from temp_table where FLAG == 'new' ")
        results <- rbind(results, select_output)      
}
```

The problem here is that you need in advance to specify the format of `results`. This can be a good thing - it makes you state explicitly what you expect, and will give an error if those expectations are violated. But it would be nice to have a quick way to bind together a data frame. Maybe the Hadleyverse has a solution?

Comment: growing objects with rbind() or c() are usually a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.

```
results <- lapply(1:8, function(i){
  #do some stuff with i
  output <- lapply(1:8, function(j){
     #do some stuff with j based on the stuff with i
  })
  do.call(rbind, output)
})
do.call(rbind, results)
```